# How to convert csv to html table in AWS Lamda using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In AWS, working on AWS Wisdom which accepts only html and text file referring this [aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/ingesting-content-to-power-real-time-recommendations-and-search-with-amazon-connect-wisdom/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
but i have data source as csv

how to convert the csv to html in lambda code and so that it passes to knowledge base of wisdom

Answer (score 0):

Write Node JS logic the same way as you would in any Node JS app. Then use the AWS Lambda run time to build the Lambda function by using the same business logic.

There is nothing special using an AWS Lambda function when you want to perform this type of task. Its the same logic. And to make it even better, there are many examples on the NET that shows you how to convert csv to html.

If you do not know how to use NODE JS to write an AWS Lambda funciton, check the following example as a reference:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javascriptv3/example_code/cross-services/lambda-for-browser